# add custom tag to prometheus custom exposed metric in drop wizard

Tags: prometheus, dropwizard, dropwizard-guice

we are trying to expose custom metrics to prometheus from dropwizard application, we are trying to get number of requests for an api endpoint like`GET_REQUEST_COUNT{endpoint='test/dosomething', method=get} 10`.
we are trying to register new metric like

```
    Meter meter=metricRegistry.meter("GET_REQUEST_COUNT");
    meter.mark();
    e.metrics().register("GET_REQUEST_COUNT",meter);
```

its giving metric like `GET_REQUEST_COUNT 10` can some one please guide how to add these tags to an metric in dropwizard .